# Read Access 2007 Database with Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2007

Using Visual Basic (and .NET 4) in Visual Studio 2010, I would like to read from an Access 2007 .accdb Database.

I used the build in Wizard to connect to the database (without importing it into the project), that is: "Add New Data Source" > "Database" > ...
A ConnectivityString is then automatically generated.

Many articles on the net speak about how to connect to a database using connections strings like `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\myFolder\myAccess2007file.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;`

But I have already several of such commands (automatically generated) in my App.config file. For example:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="Wolf_Calc.My.MySettings.wolf_calcConnectionString"
            connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\wolf-calc.accdb"
            providerName="System.Data.OleDb" />
```

Can I then just start writing queries in my code and just do something like
`value = table1.SearchCriterion("x").SearchRange("y")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the Wizard to add a Data Source, the connection strings are automatically created. But there are still some more steps to do in order to be able to use properly the Database.

1. Create the [TableAdapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tthwx%28v=vs.100%29#Y0). To do so, drag a table from the Data Source pane onto a form.
2. Load the data into a table you can use. For example, let's say I have a database named StarTrek containing a table Enterprise. The following line loads the data into the Enterprise table:

   ```
   Me.EnterpriseTableAdapter.Fill(Me.StarTrekDataSet.Enterprise)
   ```
3. Create a scalar query. It will find a single value into your table. In the Data Designer, add a query to the Enterprise table (right click on the TableAdapter zone).
   If the desired result is the age (column "Age") of Mister Spock (column "Name"), the query will be:

   ```
   ' Access Database
   SELECT Age FROM Enterprise WHERE (Name = ?)

   ' for an SQL Database
   SELECT Age FROM Enterprise WHERE Name = [@Name]
   ```
4. The search can now take place. Let's say you named the query ScalarQueryAge. The following displays the age of Mister Spock into a label.

   ```
   Dim AgeAdapter As New StarTrekDataSetTableAdapters.EnterpriseTableAdapter
   Dim Age As Integer = CType(AgeAdapter.ScalarQueryAge("Mister Spock"), Integer)
   LabelAgeMisterSpock.Text = "He is actually " & Age & "!!"
   ```